# navsat_transform_node gives zero output and warning in robot_localisation_node gives a warning - could not obtain transform

Tags: ros, navigation, robot-localization, navsat-transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello I am new to ROS and using Robot_localisation package. As given in the tutorial I ran two instances of ekf_localisation. My navsat transform node gives zero output and I keep getting a warning : Could not obtain transform from gps_link to base_link. Error was "gps_link" passed to lookupTransform argument source_frame does not exist.

My launch file is :-

```
<!-- Test launch file for two EKF instances and one navsat_transform instance -->

<launch>

  <node pkg="tf2_ros" type="static_transform_publisher" name="bl_imu" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 1 base_link imu_link" />

  <!-- Local (odom) instance -->
  <node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" name="ekf_localization_local" clear_params="true">
    <param name="frequency" value="30"/>
    <param name="sensor_timeout" value="0.1"/>
    <param name="two_d_mode" value="true"/>

    <param name="map_frame" value="map"/>
    <param name="odom_frame" value="odom"/>
    <param name="base_link_frame" value="base_link"/>
    <param name="world_frame" value="odom"/>

    <param name="transform_time_offset" value="0.0"/>

    <param name="odom0" value="/RosAria/pose"/>
    <param name="imu0" value="/imu_data"/>

    <rosparam param="odom0_config">[false, false, false,
                                    false, false, false,
                                    true, true, true,
                                    false, false, true,
                                    false, false, false]</rosparam>

    <rosparam param="imu0_config">[false, false, false,
                                   true,  true,  true,
                                   false, false, false,
                                   true,  true,  true,
                                   true,  true,  true]</rosparam>

    <param name="odom0_differential" value="false"/>
    <param name="imu0_differential" value="false"/>

    <param name="odom0_relative" value="false"/>
    <param name="imu0_relative" value="false"/>

    <param name="imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration" value="true"/>
    <param name="print_diagnostics" value="true"/>

    <param name="odom0_queue_size" value="10"/>
    <param name="imu0_queue_size" value="10"/>

    <param name="debug"           value="false"/>
    <param name="debug_out_file"  value="debug_ekf_localization.txt"/>

    <remap from="/odometry/filtered" to="/odometry/filtered/local"/>
  </node>

  <!-- Global (map) instance -->
  <node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" name="ekf_localization_global" clear_params="true">
    <param name="frequency" value="30"/>
    <param name="sensor_timeout" value="0.1"/>
    <param name="two_d_mode" value="true"/>

    <param name="map_frame" value="map"/>
    <param name="odom_frame" value="odom"/>
    <param name="base_link_frame" value="base_link"/>
    <param name="world_frame" value="map"/>

    <param name="transform_time_offset" value="0.0"/>

    <param name="odom0" value="/RosAria/pose"/>
    <param name="odom1" value="/odometry/gps"/>
    <param name="imu0" value="/imu_data"/>

    <rosparam param="odom0_config">[false, false, false,
                                    false, false, false,
                                    true, true, true,
                                    false, false, true,
                                    false, false, false]</rosparam>

    <rosparam param="odom1_config">[true, true, false,
                                    false, false, false,
                                    false, false, false,
                                    false, false, false,
                                    false, false, false]</rosparam>

    <rosparam param="imu0_config">[false, false, false,
                                   true,  true,  true,
                                   false, false, false,
                                   true,  true,  true,
                                   true,  true,  true]</rosparam>

    <param name="odom0_differential" value="false"/>
    <param name="odom1_differential" value="false"/>
    <param name="imu0_differential" value="false"/>

    <param name="odom0_relative" value="false"/>
    <param name="odom1_relative" value="false"/>
    <param name="imu0_relative" value="false"/>

    <param name="imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration" value="true"/>
    <param name="print_diagnostics" value="true"/>

    <param name="odom0_queue_size" value="10"/>
    <param name="odom1_queue_size" value="10"/>
    <param name="imu0_queue_size" value="10"/>

    <param name="debug"           value="false"/>
    <param name="debug_out_file"  value="debug_ekf_localization.txt"/>

    <remap from="/odometry/filtered" to="/odometry/filtered/global"/>
 </node>

 <!-- navsat_transform -->
 <node pkg="robot_localization" type="navsat_transform_node" name="navsat_transform" respawn="true" output="screen">
    <param name="frequency" value="30"/>
    <param name="delay" value="3"/>
    <param name="magnetic_declination_radians" value="0.05"/>
    <param name="yaw_offset" value="0"/>
    <param name="zero_altitude" value="true"/>
    <param name="broadcast_utm_transform" value="true"/>
    <param name="publish_filtered_gps" value="true"/>
    <param name="use_odometry_yaw" value="false"/>
    <param name="wait_for_datum" value="false"/>

    <remap from="/odometry/filtered" to="/odometry/filtered/global"/>
    <remap from="/gps/fix" to="/gps_data"/>
    <remap from="/imu/data" to="/imu_data"/>
  </node>

</launch>
```

I have also attached a bag file of my sensor data
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3oOeVRB6N26S3E4VEx2dk5WUGs

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236908/navsat_transform_node-gives-zero-output-and-warning-in-robot_localisation_node-gives-a-warning---could-not-obtain-transform/) by [Anirvan0102](https://answers.ros.org/users/27058/anirvan0102/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2016-06-14

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2016-06-14**:
Thanks for this. There's an issue on the GH page for `r_l` regarding this very thing, so I'll look into it today or tomorrow.

**Comment by [Anirvan0102](https://answers.ros.org/users/27058/anirvan0102/) on 2016-06-14**:
Hello Tom, thanks for replying so quick. I included a static transform of base_link ->gps_link in the launch file and the warning message stopped also navsat_transform node gave the output in robot's local frame .

**Comment by [Anirvan0102](https://answers.ros.org/users/27058/anirvan0102/) on 2016-06-14**:
this was the line I added in the launch file

but I am getting terrible output from the odometry/filtered/global

**Comment by [asimay_y](https://answers.ros.org/users/20955/asimay_y/) on 2016-06-14**:
hi, @Anirvan0102, can you check your `/odometry/gps` topic ? is it NAN when you set use_odometry_yaw= false in navsat_transform_node?
I met the same problem with you. but I just got one warning info of it, because I set the static tf transform.

**Comment by [Anirvan0102](https://answers.ros.org/users/27058/anirvan0102/) on 2016-06-14**:
Hey asimay_y, it is not NAN but the pose was exact zero and it was not changing as I was changing my robot's position. Later I set the static tf and I was getting the ouput of odometry/gps but my odometry/filtered/global was giving poor estimate.

**Comment by [asimay_y](https://answers.ros.org/users/20955/asimay_y/) on 2016-06-14**:
can you share your rosbag files and node graph?
I also get poor estimate, and digging the cause..

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2016-06-15**:
Where is the attached bag file?

**Comment by [Anirvan0102](https://answers.ros.org/users/27058/anirvan0102/) on 2016-06-15**:
Sure asimay_y ... here is my bag file https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3oOeVRB6N26S3E4VEx2dk5WUGs. My launch file is https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3oOeVRB6N26MVdGdllzVE1yMEk. I will be thankful to you if you could find out some solution, I have been stuck here for quite a time

**Comment by [Anirvan0102](https://answers.ros.org/users/27058/anirvan0102/) on 2016-06-15**:
Hello Tom, I have added it Another update- I think there might be some problem with my imu_data because I ignored the imu and used odometry yaw and my odometry/filtered/global output improved. Here's my current launch file https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3oOeVRB6N26a1ZxdFhpeUE0Z2M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First, grab the latest source from the [upstream repository](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization).

Second, fix the following issues:

1. Not sure how you recorded your bag file, but it looks to me like something other than `ekf_localization_node` is publishing the *odom*->*base_link* transform for your robot. You can't have two nodes publishing the same transform. Looking at the ROSARIA [code](https://github.com/amor-ros-pkg/rosaria/blob/cd0758033bf622e2662f347cdf5eea92a7054b4b/RosAria.cpp#L565), it appears to always publish the *odom*->*base_link* transform, and it appears you can't configure it. You'll have to either modify the ROSARIA code, use a different Pioneer ROS driver, or get rid of your *odom* instance of `ekf_localization_node`.
2. (Minor, doesn't really affect anything) You have `two_d_mode` set to *true*, but you are fusing lots of 3D variables, including Z velocity from your odometry source and roll, pitch, their velocities, and Z acceleration from the IMU. Those will be ignored unless you turn of `two_d_mode`.
3. In your *odom* EKF instance, you are fusing odometry variables that make sense, namely, the velocities. However, in your *map* instance, you are fusing absolute X and Y from *both* your GPS and your whee odometry. Those will probably not agree with each other, and the filter is going to jump back and forth rapidly.
4. You are fusing the output of the *odom* EKF as an input to the *map* EKF. For a number of reasons, this isn't a good idea. Use the same raw input data for both.
5. For some reason, your `RosAria/pose` topic has horrific covariances for yaw and yaw velocity, on the order of 1000.0. I'm going to venture a guess that the error on your rotational velocity is *not* 1000.0. This issue is very important, because it's going to cause strange behavior in the filter output. For example, when the robot turns, you may see lateral motion instead. This **must** be fixed.
6. Your IMU data is really suspect. First, it's very low frequency, but beyond that, it also is all over the place. Do a `rostopic echo /imu/data` and watch it for a little.

You need to go back and do one thing at a time: make sure all your raw sensor data conforms to standards and is correct. Then fuse one sensor - e.g., odometry - into an EKF and *make sure* the output makes sense. Then fuse another sensor and verify again.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2016-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Anirvan0102](https://answers.ros.org/users/27058/anirvan0102/) on 2016-06-15**:
Thank you Tom. I will try to make the necessary changes in the code.